# Cannot find module '@uppy/core' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, npm, uppy

I'm trying to run Uppy React example from official site https://uppy.io/docs/react/. I'm new with React, I installed

`npm install @uppy/react`

but it showed next errors:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have installed core and tus :-D

```
npm install @uppy/core
npm install @uppy/tus
```